# 401 unauthorized on API with different port

Tags: angular, spring, web-services, jhipster, azure-ad-b2c

I have a project generated by JHipster. Spring for backend and Angular for frontend. I use Azure b2c like IDP oauth2.

There are different webservices in the project that are set on different ports (/api/account on port 8080, /api/get_template on port 8082).

The sign-in/sign-on flow works regular; I can login, b2c returns me on redirect Uri and I can call services defined on /api/account and it gives me response status 200.

When I tried to do a get call on api/get_template the server gives me unauthorized status. The only thing I did is to set proxy config in this way: for the context "/api/account" the target is set to "localhost:8080" instead for the context "/api/get_template" the target is set to "localhost:8082".

I don't know what I can do...any suggestions?

this is my proxy.config.json

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
  context: [
      '/api/account',
      '/services',
      '/management',
      '/swagger-resources',
      '/v2/api-docs',
      '/h2-console',
      '/oauth2',
      '/login',
      '/auth'
  ],
  target: "http://localhost:8080",
  secure: false,
  loglevel: "debug",
  changeOrigin: false
  },
  {
context: [
    '/api/get_template'
],
target: "http://localhost:8084",
secure: false,
loglevel: "debug",
changeOrigin: false
}
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

and this is my securityConfiguration for folder microservice

```
            package it.test.webservices.config;
            
            import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
            import it.test.webservices.security.SecurityUtils;
            import it.test.webservices.security.oauth2.JwtGrantedAuthorityConverter;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
            import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
            import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
            import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
            import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
            import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
            import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
            import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
            import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
            import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
            import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
            import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper;
            import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUserAuthority;
            import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
            import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;
            import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
            import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
            import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter;
            import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
            import org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport;
            
            import java.util.HashSet;
            import java.util.Set;
            
            
            @EnableWebSecurity
            @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
            @Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
            public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
            
                private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
            
                /*@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oidc.issuer-uri}")
                private String issuerUri;*/
            
                private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;
                private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;
            
                public SecurityConfiguration(CorsFilter corsFilter, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
                    this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
                    this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
                    this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
                }
            
                @Override
                public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
                    web.ignoring()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
                        .antMatchers("/test/**");
                }
            
               /* @Override
                public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                    // @formatter:off
                    http
                        .csrf()
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .and()
                        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
                        .exceptionHandling()
                            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
                            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
                    .and()
                        .headers()
                        .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
                    .and()
                        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
                    .and()
                        .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
                    .and()
                        .frameOptions()
                        .deny()
                    .and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers("/websocket/tracker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                        .antMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .and()
                        .oauth2Login()
                    .and()
                        .oauth2ResourceServer()
                            .jwt()
                            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
                            .and()
                        .and()
                            .oauth2Client();
                    // @formatter:on
                }*/
            
            
                @Override
                protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                    http
                        .csrf()
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .and()
                        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
                        .exceptionHandling()
                            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
                            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
                    .and()
                        .headers()
                        .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
                    .and()
                        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
                    .and()
                        .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
                    .and()
                        .frameOptions()
                        .deny()
                    .and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/api/**") .hasAuthority("SCOPE_Api.Read")
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                    .and()
                        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
            //            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            //            .jwt()
            //            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter());
                }
            
            
            
                Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter() {
                    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
                    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new JwtGrantedAuthorityConverter());
                    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
                }
                /**
                 * Map authorities from "groups" or "roles" claim in ID Token.
                 *
                 * @return a {@link GrantedAuthoritiesMapper} that maps groups from
                 * the IdP to Spring Security Authorities.
                 */
            
                @Bean
                public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
                    return (authorities) -> {
                        Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            
                        authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                            // Check for OidcUserAuthority because Spring Security 5.2 returns
                            // each scope as a GrantedAuthority, which we don't care about.
                            if (authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority) {
                                OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                                mappedAuthorities.addAll(SecurityUtils.extractAuthorityFromClaims(oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo().getClaims()));
                            }
                        });
                        return mappedAuthorities;
                    };
                }
            
            
                /*
            
                @Bean
                JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
                    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuerUri);
            
                    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getOauth2().getAudience());
                    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri);
                    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);
            
                    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
            
                    return jwtDecoder;
                }
               */
            }
```

I tried to test the backend service with postman...I do a login, and if I take the authorization bearer and I hardcoded it in the header of my angular http get function '/api/get_template' works....I have to manage myself the access token with angular? Or something is wrong?

Comment: I edited the document. I'm a frontend developer and I don't know very well spring boot...

Comment: As you know proxy.config.json is made for development only because it uses webpack dev server.What is your architecture for production? It looks like a candidate for a JHipster API gateway

Comment: There were some mistakes....I edited something in the description.

Comment: Anyway I have two differents backend...

Comment: Do you have same security configuration for both services? You did not answer about the production architecture.

Comment: Yes, I have same security configuration. Why?

Comment: Because I suppose that you get an error 401 only on one of the 2 services. You still did not answer about the production architecture.